# Interactive plotting of spatial data and attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point, geopandas, plotly

Let's say I have 100 points each with unique (x, y) coordinates on a map. Each of these points has a measurement `"t"`: Time and `"j"`: Response data. `"t"` and `"j"` are arrays each with a length of 10 values.

How can I interactively plot (`"t"` and `"j"`) curves from some manually selected points (e.g., using the mouse) from the map? In other words, I would like to select some points and see a plot instantly showing the `"t"`,`"j"` curves for the selected points together (in one plot). This will help me understand how `"t"`,`"j"` curves change spatially or based on the location.

I know ArcGIS provides a scatter plot, but `"t"` and `"j"` should be single points (not 10 values for each variable as in my case). I am not sure if there is any other software (QGIS) or a Python package that can help me do this in a fairly easy manner.

If this is possible, it can be very helpful for many applications to understand spatial variability.

Comment: The plugin DataPlotly can make scatter plots, on selected geometries, also selecting in graph will select points in map (two way interactive). I don't understand "t and j should be single points (not 10 values for each variable as in my case)"

Comment: @Jamal: your data consists of a single point with attributes t="1,2,3,4" and j="20,30,11,44"? I cannot coerce dataplotly to plot from that. You could always write some python code to do what you want, and this github issue https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/issues/257 is about a similar problem to yours and has some python code to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dataset structured like this (see [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tilmanb/6b697a3809106bfdb90282c6c802ff3b/raw/dc6f0d2b2ddbdd1dd07ea09c7bef7482a99a062b/map.geojson) for full data)

```
"features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "timestamps": "1,2,3",
        "values": "4,2,3"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.74560546875,
          52.89564866211353
        ]
      }
    },
```

and the following python code (needs plotly, which can be installed by installing the "dataplotly" qgis plugin) run in the python console/editor

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

vl = iface.activeLayer()

traces = []
for i in vl.getSelectedFeatures():
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x = list(map(float,i["timestamps"].split(","))),
        y = list(map(float,i["values"].split(",")))
    )
    traces.append(trace)

layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend = True,
)

fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

I can create scatterplots from the time series data in the attribute "timestamps" and the values in the attribute "values" of the selected qgis feature.

[image: scatterplot from the feature time series]

Comment: Thank you very much @til_b, this is exactly what im looking for, and i assume this can display multiple selected 'traces' at the same time ? I'm new to QGIS and im not sure how to start/plot the structured data features initially (where to input the structured data)?. I understand that after i have my data plotted, ill use this python code in the editor in QGIS to run it. Thank you again

Comment: Yes, it can be used as you describe. You can select multiple features and then run this code in the python console, you will get multiple traces. A browser window will open with the plot inside it.
You need a vector layer with the attributes "timestamps" and "values". The vector layer can be of any type supported by qgis (shapefile, geojson as in my example gist, sqlite database, postgres database...). For a tutorial on vector data in qgis see https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_data.html .

Comment: Thanks, i was able to import the geojson file as a vector layer. However, when i run the code i get a message saying "AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'show'". I checked the directories for QGIS: <module 'qgis' from 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\\qgis\\__init__.py'> and that of plotly: <module 'plotly' from 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\__init__.py'>. They seem to be different, not sure if i should have them in the same directory for the code to run. Any ideas?

Comment: From a cursory google search it seems like your plotly version is too old. See this Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793602/2168905

Comment: Thanks, I re-installed the newer version of QGIS and it worked. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you're interested in a python package... have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)!

There's an example in the docs that shows how to do exactly what you're describing... it looks like this:

[image: EOmaps example]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. is it possible to plot several points together at the same time (overlay in one plot)?

Comment: hey, yep that should be easy to implement... (just don't reset the plots on every click)